# How does one show that for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ a quadratic satisfies $| f(x) - f(x^*) | \leq a| x - x^* |$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I was trying to understand why for sufficiently small epsilon we had:

$$ |f(x) - f(x^*) | \leq a |x - x^* | $$

for a quadratic of the form $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + x $ and $x^*$ is the minimizer of $f(x)$. It seems intuitive that as one approaches the minimizer $x^*$ the quadratic must be decreasing faster than the linear function $|x - x^* |$, however, I can't seem to get that exact inequality.

This is my (very hand wavy) reasoning (if I knew more maths like real analysis I would try such a technique, though, feel free to contribute such an answer, I am willing to learn it if I need to).

I want to show $ |f(x) - f(x^*) | \leq a |x - x^* | $. For very small $\epsilon$ (changes in x), changes in $f$ are basically equal to the derivative. Thus we have that we want to compare $ f'(x) \epsilon = (2ax + b) \epsilon $ to $\epsilon$ (i.e. we want to compare the change in f with the change in x). It seems to me that for changes very close to the minimizer not only are changes the derivative but the derivative is closer and closer to zero (and thus $<1$). In that case I'd guess the following should hold:

$$ |f(x) - f(x^*) | =  f'(x) \epsilon = (2ax + b) \epsilon \leq \epsilon = | x - x^*|$$

since $f'(x) = (2ax + b) < 1$ (closer to $x^*$). But in that case, if $a > 0$ (and constant) then

$$ |f(x) - f(x^*) |  \leq a \epsilon = a| x - x^*|$$

should obviously hold true too. I do not see why we would **need** the $a$ for the inequality to hold true. Its true that the $a$ is unnecessary, right? If my reasoning is completely wrong, can I be told **why** so?

Comment: Near the minimum, the function is increasing (or decreasing) *slowly*.

Comment: $f(x)=a(x-x^*)^2+f(x^*)$, then $a|x-x^*|^2<a|x-x^*|$ when $|x-x^*|<1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust so do you necessarily need $a$ for it to be correct?

Comment: Do you see $a$ in $| x - x^*|<1$ ??? Where is it ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust $a$ is in ur equation $a | x - x^* |^2 < a | x - x^*|$ and you end with the factor $a$. By my "argument" seems to work without requiring to have that $a$ in the upper bound and simply get $| f(x) - f(x^*) | \leq | x - x^*|$ is what I meant to say.

Comment: @Pinocchio: your words are ambiguous, "$a$ is necessary" doesn't have a clear meaning.

Comment: @YvesDaoust not sure why its ambiguous but I simply meant that if the upper bound required to have the factor of a. What I meant is, why does the coefficient of the $x^2$ term have to be included in the upper bound. If we remove it and simple have $ |x - x^* |$, is that still a correct upper bound? Hope that clears my question :)

Answer (score 1):

Show that $ |f(x) - f(x^*) | \leq a |x - x^* | $ for $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + x $ and $x^*$.

Fix $x -x^* =  \varepsilon$ and substitute in $f(x)$ to obtain

$$
f(x) = a(x^*+\varepsilon)^2 + b(x^*+\varepsilon) + (x^*+\varepsilon) \\
f(x) = ax^{*2}+bx^* + x^* + (2ax^*+b+1)\varepsilon+a\varepsilon^2
$$
What is $x^*$? The minimizer of the quadratic form, so let's take the first-order condition $2ax^{*}+b + 1 = 0$. Substitution in the above expression gives us
$$
f(x) = ax^{*2}+bx^* + x^* +a\varepsilon^2.
$$
Now, assume $a\geq 0$ and write
$$
|f(x) - f(x^*) | = |a\varepsilon^2| \\
|f(x) - f(x^*) | \leq a|\varepsilon| \\
$$
where the inequality comes from the fact that for small $\varepsilon$, we have $\varepsilon^2 \leq \varepsilon$. Direct substitution of $\varepsilon$ in the last expression gives the desired conclusion.

Comment: I understand your reasoning and it makes sense. But what still doesn't make sense to me is that the $a$ seems unnecessary. If you look at my argument I was able to conclude $| f(x) - f(x^*)| \leq |x - x^* | $ without the need of the $a$. Was my argument incorrect or something?

Comment: Your argument is indeed incorrect, starting with your derivative argument.

Comment: why is it incorrect?

Comment: The very first equality in your proof is wrong. Just replicate the proof the way I did it. Hopefully it will be clear what is incorrect.

Comment: I totally understand your proof and find it quite clever! The thing I just don't understand is why my first equality is wrong. For sufficiently small $\epsilon$, isn't the change in $f$ just equal to the "rate of change of x" times the "change in x"? In this case, the derivative times the very small $\epsilon$? Thanks for your patience and contributions btw! :D

Comment: First, you 'guess' that $|f(x) - f(x^*) | =  |f'(x) \varepsilon|$ whereas as you can see from my proof $|f(x) - f(x^*) | = | a\varepsilon^2|$. Neglecting absolute values, for your equality to hold you need $f'(x)  =a\varepsilon$, but you find (wrongly) that $f'(x) =  (2ax + b)$ (note that there should be a +1 in this derivative). Substituting $x$ by $x^* +\varepsilon$ may solve this problem. 
Second, you claim (after correction) $(2ax + b +1 ) \epsilon \leq \epsilon$, which is equivalent to say that for small $\varepsilon$,  $b \leq 0$. If this an assumption of your problem? I don't think so.

Comment: maybe my misconception is that for very small values $$ \frac{d f(x)}{ dx} \neq \frac{ \Delta f}{\Delta x}$$. I thought that was true just from the definition of a derivative. I thought that for super small values the derivative was in fact, the change in the function. Maybe thats my misconception?

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming $a>0$.) You can show this without calculus. Writing the quadratic $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ in the form
$$
f(x)=a\left(x+\frac b{2a}\right)^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\tag1$$
(i.e., we're just [completing the square](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/completing-square.html)), we see that the minimizer of the quadratic is
$$x^*=-\frac b{2a}$$
and the minimum value of $f$ is
$$f(x^*)=c-\frac{b^2}{4a}.$$
Plugging all of this into (1) and rearranging, we've just proved that
$$f(x)-f(x^*)=a(x-x^*)^2,$$
which implies
$$|f(x)-f(x^*)|= a|x-x^*|^2.$$
This should get you to the result you're looking for: if $|x-x^*|<1$, then
$$|f(x)-f(x^*)|\le a|x-x^*|.$$

Comment: how did you get rid of the square? From your penultimate line to the last lime?

Comment: Also, something I don't understand is that the $a$ seems unnecessary. If you look at my argument I was able to conclude $| f(x) - f(x^*)| \leq |x - x^* | $ without the need of the $a$. Was my argument incorrect or something?

Comment: To answer your first question: It's the condition $|x-x^*|<1$. If that condition holds then it knocks out one of the terms in $|x-x^*|^2$.

Comment: To answer your second question: Yes, you don't need $a$. You can eliminate $a$ by revising the the nearness condition to $|x-x^*|<1/a$.